# Create list of cell addresses contained in a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

I'm looking for a single arrayformula to convert a specified range, such as `B2:D4`, into a list of addresses (not values!) contained in that range, in this case `B2,B3,B4,C2,C3,C4,D2,D3,D4`.

**Attempts so far**

Google didn't come up with useful results.

I have tried to count through the array, and are able to extract two list of numbers corresponding to the row and column numbers, but have failed to come up with a combined formula.

Column calc:

```
=ArrayFormula(
   ROW(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),ROW())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()+
      COLUMNS(B2:D4)
   -1,ROW()),"$","")))-ROW()+
      CELL("col", B2:D4)
)
```

Row calc:

```
=ArrayFormula(
   ROW(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),ROW())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()+
      ROWS(B2:D4)
   -1,ROW()),"$","")))-ROW()+
      CELL("row", B2:D4)
)
```

Note on the above formulas, the ROWS()/COLUMNS() function is used to get the range size, and the CELL() is used to get the range start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is fairly strait forward, please see the code below:

```
=textjoin(",",true,arrayformula(address(row(B2:D4),column(B2:D4),4)))
```

You can change the last 4 to a 1 if you want absolute references.